# Does the recent question reputation change affect question bans?

Tags: support, reputation, post-ban

Question upvotes were recently changed in value from +5 to +10: see [We’re Rewarding the Question Askers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers).

I'm not sure, but it seems possible this may affect [question bans](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th):

> To avoid bypassing the filter its internal rules are a secret

**Question**: Does the recent question reputation change affect question bans?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, it doesn't. While the blocks are partly based on voting, it is based on the votes themselves - the amount of reputation gained/lost has no effect on how the block operates.

However, gaining a sufficient amount of reputation could cause the user to appear more trustworthy overall, which could get them past [some other rate limits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide).

Answer (score 1):

IIRC question ban doesn't work on reputation, but rather one's question history, including up/down numbers. So whatever value a question upvote worths, the mechanism of question bamming remains unaffected.

Comment: Please remind me again what IIRC stands for.

Comment: If I Recall Correctly.